# Xcode 4: Drawing a Grid or Table

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am surprised/befuddled to see that Xcode apparently does not contain any drawing primitives (line , rectangle, circle, etc.) as part of the standard set of controls.  I'd like to have something like this show up on my form/storyboard:

```
--------------------
|         |        |
--------------------
|         |        |
--------------------
|                  |
--------------------
|                  |
|                  |
--------------------
```

In the actual app, these lines would be solid of course.  Within each of these "cells" I'd like to put various controls (labels, textboxes, etc). No user interactions will occur with the lines themselves.  They are there just as a visual aid.

I've checked out the table view controller; it does not seem flexible enough to build something like this (although I could be wrong about this).  I've also seen examples of sub-classing the UIView and drawing the the lines/rectangles programmatically; this seems awfully overwrought for just getting some lines up on the screen.  Any suggestions as to how to best resolve this problem is appreciated.  Newbie iOS developer here if you had not figured that out already.

Comment: Im not going to give you a working solution, because many MANY examples exist, But look at [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html)

Comment: FYI - Xcode 4 is a few years out of date. You should update to avoid learning obsolete tools and APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UIBezierPath to create and draw any shape you want. You could create a custom subclass of UIView that contains a bezier path and draws it in it's drawRect method. You could also use Quartz drawing methods directly, or attach a CAShapeLayer to your view. (A CAShapeLayer uses a CGPath, which is the Core Foundation shape drawing object that is used internally by UIBezierPath